# Threads in Java VS Threads in Application Server/Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, application-server

From the Head First Java book, I know that threads in java doesn't run parallelly, but JVM just switches between the threads which seem to us like running parallelly. And these threads run in a single JVM which itself a process that runs in one core of the Computer.

Here is the content from the book - **" With more than one call stack, you get the *appearance* of having multiple things happen at the same time. In reality, only a true multiprocessor system can actually do more than one thing at a time, but with Java threads, it can *appear* that you’re doing several things simultaneously. In other words, execution can move back and forth between stacks so rapidly that you feel as though all stacks are executing at the same time. Remember, Java is just a process running on your underlying OS. So first, Java *itself* has to be ‘the currently executing process’ on the OS. "**

My doubt is, does the tomcat threads and application server threads which are created per user request are also not run parallelly but JVM which runs on a single core (on which application server runs) just switches between the threads?
OR does threads really run parallelly on different cores?

I have been struggling with this question since many days. I have googled lot about this, but couldn't find the answer. So posting it here, hoping someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are wrong about that the threads are not running in parallel.  It might have been true for some very old JVM's though.

Comment: Many years ago, processors (on home computers) used to have a single hardware thread.

Comment: If your hardware has more than one core, then Java threads will use them.  Tomcat worker threads are Java threads.   Your real problem is that you have *misread* or *misunderstood* what the Head First Java book says.  (I cannot believe that it would say that threads don't run in parallel.  But it is plausible that it says that threads don't **necessarily** run in parallel ... or something like that.)

Comment: For the record, Java has supported threads running on multiple cores since Java 1.2 ... and earlier for some platforms.  Java 1.2 was released in 1998, 5 years before [Head First Java](https://www.powells.com/book/head-first-java-1st-edition-9780596004651) was first published.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. Yes, what you said is correct, Head First java is old edition. But it is mentioned Java Scheduler is the one that decides which thread should run currently and after that which thread should run.

Comment: @StephenC Please find the quote that I took from the book - Typically, a thread moves back and forth between runnable and running, as the JVM thread scheduler selects a thread to run and then kicks it back out so another thread gets a chance.  The book emphasizes on the job of thread scheduler who controls the current working thread and switches between the threads. Can you please explain whether it is true at the time of the book is written and know it got changed the way the threads work?

Comment: That does NOT say, or imply that two or more threads cannot run in parallel on different cores.  In fact, if two or more threads are runnable and cores are available, then that is what WILL happen.  Like I said, you have misread / misunderstood the book.  Or ... if you insist that you have not misunderstood what it is saying, then the book is just plain wrong, and you should throw it in a rubbish bin and go buy a newer / better text book.  The choice is yours :-)

Comment: Thank you, got it. Is there any way that I can see or verify that the threads are actually running in multiple cores, but not just on one core?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.